# Digital Metaphors Report Builder 16.0 How can I assign shape visibility dynmically

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

I wish to make an area of a worksheet grey if it does not apply. I'm thinking of using a shape with visibility depending on some boolean value in the data pipeline. Can anyone describe how to access the visibility attribute of a shape, or suggest another method of dynamic shading?

Answer (score 3):

If the area is (for example) in the DetailBand, you can set this up in the BeforePrint event.

I'm assuming you've set transparency and colour of Shape1 in designer.

```
procedure TSomeFormOrDM.ppDetailBand1BeforePrint(Sender: TObject);
var
  doGrey: boolean;
begin
  doGrey := ppDBPipeline1['SomeBooleanTrigger'];
  ppShape1.visible:=doGrey;
end;
```

Instead of a shape, you could always drop a range in the band. If you did that, you'd need to change colour, not visible (because making the range not visible would of course also hide every element embedded/parented by the range).

EdB

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your shape and give if a fill color from the Design tab.
2. Send to Back
3. Go to RAP (calculation tab)
4. Create the conditions for visible and not visible (You might need to create a variable in the Design tab and set it Not Visible)
5. Add conditional code for when you what it visible and add the code:  ShapeX.Visible :=True;
   (replace the X with actual value that is assigned to the shape)
6. For conditions where you don't want it visible use:
   ShapeX.Visible :=False;

Below is an example that shades alternating rows to make the report easier to read.
I hope this helps.

`if Shade.Value=1 then begin`
`Shape2.Visible :=True;`
`Shade.Value :=2;`
`end`
`else begin`
`Shape2.Visible :=False;`
`Shade.Value :=1;`
`end;`